# How do you write to HDFS from beam?

Tags: apache-beam, apache-beam-io

I'm trying to write a Beam pipeline that runs using the SparkRunner, reads from a local file, and writes to HDFS.

Here's a minimal example:

Options class -

```
package com.mycompany.beam.hdfsIOIssue;

import org.apache.beam.runners.spark.SparkPipelineOptions;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.io.hdfs.HadoopFileSystemOptions;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.options.Description;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.options.PipelineOptions;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.options.Validation;

public interface WritingToHDFSOptions extends PipelineOptions, SparkPipelineOptions, HadoopFileSystemOptions {

  @Validation.Required
  @Description("Path of the local file to read from")
  String getInputFile();
  void setInputFile(String value);

  @Validation.Required
  @Description("Path of the HDFS to write to")
  String getOutputFile();
  void setOutputFile(String value);

}
```

Beam main class -

```
package com.mycompany.beam.hdfsIOIssue;

import org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.io.FileBasedSink;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.io.TextIO;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.io.fs.ResourceId;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.options.PipelineOptionsFactory;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.values.PCollection;

public class WritingToHDFS {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    PipelineOptionsFactory.register(WritingToHDFSOptions.class);

    WritingToHDFSOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.fromArgs(args).withValidation()
      .as(WritingToHDFSOptions.class);

    Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(options);

    buildPipeline(p, options);

    p.run();
  }

  static void buildPipeline(Pipeline p, WritingToHDFSOptions options) {
    PCollection<String> input = p.apply("ReadLines", TextIO.read().from(options.getInputFile()));

    ResourceId resource = FileBasedSink.convertToFileResourceIfPossible(options.getOutputFile());
    TextIO.Write write = TextIO.write().to(resource);
    input.apply("WriteLines", write);
  }
}
```

Running it like:

```
spark-submit test --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster --class com.mycompany.beam.hdfsIOIssue.WritingToHDFS my-project-bundled-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar --runner=SparkRunner --inputFile=testInput --outputFile=hdfs://testOutput
```

What I expect to happen: It reads the lines in the local testInput file and writes them to a new file names testOutput in my hdfs home directory.

What actually happens: Nothing, as far as I can tell. Spark says the job completes successfully and I see the Beam steps in the logs, but there isn't a file or directory named testOutput written to hdfs or to my local directory. Maybe it's getting written locally on the spark executor nodes but I don't have access to those to check.

I'm guessing either that I'm using the TextIO interface wrong or that I need to do more to configure the Filesystem, not just add it to my PipelineOptions interface. But I can't find documentation that explains how to do that.

Answer (score 2):

I think your options should look something like the following :

```
--inputFile=hdfs:///testInput --outputFile=hdfs:///testOutput
```

You might also want to wait until the pipeline is finished so you can see the result:

```
p.run().waitUntilFinish();
```

You can find a simple complete working example of an HDFS write (Avro files) [here](https://github.com/gbif/beam-perf/blob/master/avro-to-avro/src/main/java/org/gbif/beam/perf/avrotoavro/BeamAvroIOTest.java)

Please be aware of ([BEAM-2277](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-2277)) which might also apply depending on the version of Beam you are running with (it would throw error). You can work around that using:

```
TextIO.Write write = TextIO.write().to(resource)
  .withTempDirectory(FileSystems.matchNewResource("hdfs:///tmp/beam-test", true));
```

If you package up your project on a public GitHub repo I will test it and help you get running.